# AS2: Simple class not working

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

So I'm trying to learn to create a public class, and this is what is in my class file:

```
    class com.RCN.Menu.Menu{

    public var title:String;
    public var menuItems:Array;

    public function createMenu(title:String, menuItems:Array) {
        return title;
    }

    function createTitleBar(title:String):Void  {
    }
}
```

and in a seperate SWF I use the code:

```
    import com.RCN.Menu.Menu;

var Accountability:Menu = createMenu("hello",[a,b,c,d]);
trace(Accountability);
```

yet Accountability traces as undefined, can anyone tell my why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the **new** keyword to make an instance of your class.

Try this:

```
public class com.RCN.Menu.Menu{

    public var title:String;
    public var menuItems:Array;

    public function Menu(title:String, menuItems:Array) {
        this.title = title;
        this.menuItems = menuItems;
    }

    public function toString():String{
       return title;
    }

}
```

And then to create your instance:

```
import com.RCN.Menu.Menu;

var Accountability:Menu = new Menu("hello",[a,b,c,d]);
trace(Accountability);
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, but Accountability now traces as an object, how do I get it to trace `title`?

Comment: `trace(Accountability.title);` or you could add a toString method to your class and then call `trace(Accountability)`. I will update the example

Comment: Idd, updated the example constructor and it should work fine now